# How to use mongo db plugin for logstash?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I need to push data to the elastic search from mongo db. There is no offcial plugin available for mongodb. the, how can I import data from mongodb and push to elastic search.

I try to use this [GIT](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb) 
 but, i cant install the plugin. I am getting error while install mongo plugin using this cmnd  `bin/plugin install logstash-input-mongodb`

**error**: bash: bin/plugin: No such file or directory
please help me to fix the issue and push data to the elastic search

Comment: how about "sudo -E /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-mongodb" ?